# Saving data from tag inputs

Tags: php, mysqli, input, tags

I am using tag inputs to get data from the user but I don't know how to use that data. How can I save it in a database?

By tag inputs, I mean like the one you see in stack overflow or in youtube.
Sorry for the short description, I don't know what else to say.

[A pic of the tag inputs in case you can not understand what in mean]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="text" name="tags[]" > 
<?php
    $tags  = $_POST['tags'];

?>
```

Comment: It will save all the tags in the form of array or text?

Comment: @ahsan will get the value as array